# Converting Mongoid to ActiveRecord for Devise-Basecamp setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I am setting up Devise-Basecamper to enable subdomain scoped authentication to extend Devise's usefulness even more. The gem might be a bit old but it seems like an ideal solution if I get everything up and running. The README.md is super clear but the only thing that threw me off is a bit of code relating to Mongoid even though I am using ActiveRecord. If you could help me write this code according to ActiveRecord I would be very grateful. I have a model called Account, which is like the company or organization.

Here's the necessary excerpt from Devise-Basecamper's readme. I have put the Mongoid code in >>> and <<<

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    helper_method :subdomain, :current_account
    before_filter :validate_subdomain, :authenticate_user!

    private # ----------------------------------------------------

    def current_acount
        # The where clause is assuming you are using Mongoid, change appropriately
        # for ActiveRecord or a different supported ORM.

     >>>@current_account ||= Association.where(subdomain: subdomain).first<<<
    end

    def subdomain
        request.subdomain
    end

    # This will redirect the user to your 404 page if the account can not be found
    # based on the subdomain.  You can change this to whatever best fits your
    # application.
    def validate_subdomain
        redirect_to '/404.html' if current_account.nil?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a typo in current_account method. It's current_account not current_acount.

so replace this line

```
def current_acount
```

with

```
def current_account
```

Second, You have change Association to Account because Account is actually Model.

Replace this line

```
@current_account ||= Association.where(subdomain: subdomain).first
```

with

```
@current_account ||= Account.where(subdomain: subdomain).first
```

Third, If you're not using mongoid then you have change where clause. e.g.

replace where clause

```
@current_account ||= Association.where(subdomain: subdomain).first
```

with

```
@current_account ||= Association.where("subdomain = ?", subdomain).first
```

Final code is here..

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    helper_method :subdomain, :current_account
    before_filter :validate_subdomain, :authenticate_user!

private # ----------------------------------------------------

def current_account
    # The where clause is assuming you are using Mongoid, change appropriately
    # for ActiveRecord or a different supported ORM.

 @current_account ||= Account.where("subdomain = ?", subdomain).first
end

def subdomain
    request.subdomain
end

# This will redirect the user to your 404 page if the account can not be found
# based on the subdomain.  You can change this to whatever best fits your
# application.
def validate_subdomain
    redirect_to '/404.html' if current_account.nil?
end
end
```